# Iterating over arrays by reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am doing some reflection work and go to a little problem.

I am trying to print objects to some GUI tree and have problem detecting arrays in a generic way.

I suggested that :

> object instanceof Iterable

Would make the job ,but it does not, (obviously applies only to Lists and Set and whoever implements it.)

So how is that i would recognice an Array Some `Object[]` , Or `long[]` or `Long[]` .. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you don't want only to check whether the object is an array, but also to iterate it:

```
if (array.getClass().isArray()) {
    int length = Array.getLength(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
        Object arrayElement = Array.get(array, i);
        System.out.println(arrayElement);
    }
}
```

(the class above is `java.lang.reflect.Array`)

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean `Object.getClass().isArray()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
if (o instanceof Object[]) {
  Object[] array = (Object[]) o;
  // now access array.length or 
  // array.getClass().getComponentType()
}
```

Comment: This is good , but it will not apply to the primitive array types. I think i found the answer : object.getClass().isArray() .. lol

Answer (score 0):

First of all, @Bozho's answer is perfectly correct.

If you want to make this to be easier useable, I've just created a method in our [little OSS utility molindo-utils](https://github.com/molindo/molindo-utils) that turns an array of unknown type into an Iterable: [ArrayUtils.toIterable(Object)](https://github.com/molindo/molindo-utils/blob/02048d6b8300a00af77507e5891f32974c10f4c1/src/main/java/at/molindo/utils/collections/ArrayUtils.java#L199)

This way, you can do:

```
// any array, e.g. int[], Object[], String[], ...
Object array = ...;
for (Object element : ArrayUtils.toIterable(array)) {
    // element of type Integer for int[]
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

See README of [molindo-utils](https://github.com/molindo/molindo-utils) on how to get molindo-utils or feel free to copy the code  if you like, just as you see fit.